# Xamarin Forms, Webview leaves a gap at the top of the Content

Tags: android, ios, webview, xamarin.forms

When I use a webview, it has gaps at the top and bottom, or if orientated horizontally it has gaps at the side. How do I make the webview fill the entire screen.

You can see in the screenshot the blue area is the background color of the content. Why doesn't the webview start at the top?

I have also added a label which correctly strats at the top of the screen.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
         x:Class="WorkingWithWebview.MyPage" >
       <ContentPage.Content>
           <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
             <Label Text="this is a label showing its not the nav bar" BackgroundColor="Red"></Label>
             <WebView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
             Source="https://www.google.com" WidthRequest="1000" HeightRequest="1000">

           </WebView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

[image]

Comment: What version of Xamarin.Forms are you using? Are you doing anything else to the layout? I don't see this behavior

Comment: Try this : Option1 : set `VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"` of `WebView` Or Option2: Set visibility of navigationbar to false if its your main page may be its a navigationbar space.

Comment: tried all of that but doesnt make any difference thx

Answer (score 0):

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
          VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <WebView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                 VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <WebView.Source>
                <HtmlWebViewSource Html="{Binding TermsAndConditions}"/>
            </WebView.Source>
        </WebView>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

This setup works well for me =)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. If you set an iOS storyboard for your app, the gap will be gone. The app will be sized based on the size of the launch screen or story board. Of nothing is set, it will leave a gap for large iPhone screen sizes.